# I need to attached more than 5 security group per Lambda in AWS, I have increase the service Quota to 16 still getting below error

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

│ Error: error modifying Lambda Function (CLM-SCANNER-AUTH-internalscanauthorizer-sit) configuration : ValidationException:
│       status code: 400, request id: d7e7da06-512f-4c84-9b30-31b90ea0554e

enter image description here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQMZk.png)

Comment: Can you share your tf code?

Comment: Can you reformat your question and put messages into blocks?